# How to retrieve words from a sentence containing Special characters?

Tags: java, regex, stanford-nlp

From the given below code::
I want to extract relations as

```
amod delhi
nsubj capital delhi 
.....etc

[amod(delhi-2, -1), nsubj(capital-5, delhi-2), cop(capital-5, is-3),
det(capital-5, the-4), root(ROOT-0, capital-5), prep_of(capital-5,
india-7)]
```

Comment: Does your input really look like this?

Answer (score 0):

If your input really looks that way then you can use this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\((\\w*)-\\d+,\\s(\\w*)-\\d+\\)");
//groups                      1       2              3
String data = "[amod(delhi-2, -1), nsubj(capital-5, delhi-2), " +
        "cop(capital-5, is-3), det(capital-5, the-4), root(ROOT-0, " +
        "capital-5), prep_of(capital-5, india-7)]";
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while (m.find()) 
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2) + " " + m.group(3));
```